# Passing Enums Into Objects in Different Files

Tags: c++, enums, game-engine, game-development

So I am currently working on a text-based RPG, and I have run into an odd issue. In working on the weapon coding, I chose to go with enums for the type and rarity of the weapon. I have already programmed everything for my `Weapon` class; yet, when I try to create a `Weapon` object, I get an error having to do with my enums -- `error: 'common' is not a type`. The relevant code is as follows:

In `Enum_Weapon.h`:

```
#ifndef ENUM_WEAPON_H_INCLUDED
#define ENUM_WEAPON_H_INCLUDED

enum rarity{common, uncommon, rare, epic, legendary};

enum weaponType{axe, bow, crossbow, dagger, gun, mace,
                polearm, stave, sword, wand, thrown};


#endif // ENUM_WEAPON_H_INCLUDED
```

And in `Weapon.h`:

```
#ifndef WEAPON_H
#define WEAPON_H

#include "Item.h"
#include "Enum_Weapon.h"

class Weapon : public Item{
    public:
        Weapon();
        Weapon(rarity r, weaponType t, std::string nam, int minDam, 
               int maxDam, int stamina = 0, int strength = 0, 
               int agility = 0, int intellect = 0);
```

The code, of course, goes on; but this is all the code that is relevant to my error. Finally, when I try to create a `Weapon` object, I get the error:

```
#ifndef LISTOFWEAPONS_H
#define LISTOFWEAPONS_H

#include "Weapon.h"
#include "Enum_Weapon.h"

class ListOfWeapons
{
    public:
        ListOfWeapons();

    protected:

    private:
        Weapon worn_greatsword(common, sword, "Worn Greatsword", 1, 2);

};

#endif // LISTOFWEAPONS_H
```

The same error also happens with the `sword` enum. I have researched the problem, but I can't find anything similar to the issue that I am having. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to declare a variable or a function?  I think you want to use `{}` (curly brackets) instead of `()` (parentheses).

Comment: Can you post the full error output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your weapon attribute was a function declaration, not a variable definition. You must pass in default values in the constructor.

```
class ListOfWeapons
{
    public:
    ListOfWeapons() :
           worn_greatsword(common, sword, "Worn Greatsword", 1, 2)
      {
         //...constructor stuff
      }

protected:

private:
    //function decl
    //Weapon worn_greatsword(common, sword, "Worn Greatsword", 1, 2);
     Weapon worn_greatsword;
};
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I actually wasn't aware that you couldn't give objects arguments before the constructor.